# Can not start Elasticsearch 7.9.1, how to solve this problem?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@server elasticsearch]# systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 二 2022-11-15 23:00:29 CST; 18s ago
Docs: https://www.elastic.co
Process: 13102 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 13102 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service

11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
11月 15 23:00:28 server.rosatina.com systemd-entrypoint[13102]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
11月 15 23:00:29 server.rosatina.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
11月 15 23:00:29 server.rosatina.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
11月 15 23:00:29 server.rosatina.com systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
11月 15 23:00:29 server.rosatina.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.

Comment: My VPS is centos 7 with Nignx and PHP 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Run 'systemctl status elasticsearch.service' and check the output, that should  show you why the process was stopped

Comment: I actually did it and it says:

Comment: I actually did it and it says:
Process: 20696 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 20696 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.

Comment: Does 'journalctl -xe' give you any more information.